# Ifelse returning NAs instead of the false value

Tags: r, if-statement

I'm running a bit of code like this:

```
DATA$a<-ifelse((DATA$b=="Yes"|DATA$c=="Yes"),"Yes","No")
```

Expecting to get a data column with both Yes and No values outputted, but instead I only get Yes values and NAs where No values should be. There definitely should be No values but they don't seem to appear at all.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Please put the output from `dput(head(DATA))` in your question!

Comment: Can you explain what are you trying to do? When the values should be "Yes" vs when they should be "No" ? Please include a reproducible example along with expected output.

Comment: You should share some of your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use

```
DATA$a<-ifelse(rowSums(DATA[c("b","c")]=="Yes",na.rm = T)>0,"Yes","No")
```

such that

```
> DATA
     b    c   a
1  Yes   No Yes
2   No   No  No
3  Yes  Yes Yes
4 <NA>  Yes Yes
5   NO <NA>  No
6 <NA> <NA>  No
```

**Dummy DATA**

```
DATA <- data.frame(b=c("Yes","No","Yes",NA,"NO",NA),c=c("No","No","Yes","Yes",NA,NA))
> DATA
     b    c
1  Yes   No
2   No   No
3  Yes  Yes
4 <NA>  Yes
5   NO <NA>
6 <NA> <NA>
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what was happening, and your solution works perfectly!